# problem with update of select formcontrol in bind which is outside formgroup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS
I have two forms which I have assigned to the content of two `tabs` **'test1'** and **'test'**, both the forms are assigned different form groups.
I want to select one form according to choice of user given in select dropdown from user
The select drop down is given at starting,outside both the form groups whose value needs to be accessed by both the forms to display correct form using `[class.active]` directive on appropriate tab content

Please help me , I am a beginner to Angular and couldn't think of the flow ahead.

*publish.component.html*

```
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col l6 s12 m12 offset-l3">



            <div class="input-field col s12 white-text">
                <select formControlName="choice">
                    <option value="instagram">Instagram post</option>
                    <option value="content">Content post</option>
                </select>
                <label>Choose type of post</label>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col l12" style="display: none;">
                    <ul class="tabs">
                        <li  class="tab col l6 disabled"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
                        <li  class="tab col l6 disabled"><a href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div [class.active]="instagramForm.get('choice').value === 'instagram' " id="test1" class="col l12 white-text">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="col s12" [formGroup]="instagramForm">
                            <div class="input-field">
                                <input id="instaToken" formControlName="instaToken" type="text" class="validate white-text">
                                <label for="instaToken">Access Token</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field">
                                <input id="link" formControlName="link" type="text" placeholder="Something like https://www.instagram.com/...." class="validate white-text">
                                <label class="active" for="link">Link to Instagram post</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-db center-align" type="submit">Submit</div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div [class.active]="instagramForm.get('choice').value === 'content' " id="test2" class="col l12 white-text">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="col s12" [formGroup]="contentForm">
                            <div class="input-field">
                                <input id="contentToken" formControlName="contentToken" type="text" class="validate white-text">
                                <label for="contentToken">Access Token</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-field">
                                <textarea id="content" formControlName="content" class="materialize-textarea white-text"></textarea>
                                <label for="content">Your Content here</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="btn-db center-align" type="submit">Submit</div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<div class="white-text" style="font-size:1em">{{ instagramForm.value | json}}</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import * as M from 'materialize-css';
declare var $:any;
import { FormBuilder,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-publish',
  templateUrl: './publish.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./publish.component.css']
})
export class PublishComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {}

  instagramForm = this.fb.group({
    choice:['instagram'],
    instaToken:[''],
    link:['']
  });

 contentForm = this.fb.group({
    choice:[''],
    contentToken:[''],
    content:['']
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems,"");


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tabs').tabs();
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Why don´t you just use [NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)? I think it will be easier for you if you are a beginner

Comment: can you guide how and where to use NgIf

Comment: Sure, use the ngIf instead of the class to check the value on the select